# If not have a camera in device, showing black background color on android

Tags: android, android-camera

Recently I used cctv camera app but if not have a camera in device, showing this **logcat** and app is died

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid/kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.BlackEyeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(PeerConnectionFactory.java:111)
    at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.BlackEyeActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:235)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my source 
**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   String nameOfFrontFacingDevice = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();
   String nameOfBackFacingDevice = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfBackFacingDevice();
   VideoCapturerAndroid capturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(nameOfFrontFacingDevice);
   . 
   . 
   . 
   }
```

if not have a camera.   `capturer` this return `null`
so , I test

```
if (capturer == null || capturer.equals("") == true) {
   try {
      rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot"});
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

and I execute app. I rebooted my device but I want if not have a camera, showing black color background

If its connected to camera then it showing `GLSurfaceView`

```
glview = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glview);
VideoRendererGui.setView(glview, null) ;
try {
     . . . .
} catch {
}
```

perhaps, I use fragment? 
please advice for me. 
I think

```
if (capturer == null || capturer.equals("") == true) {
   // showing black background ??..
  }
```

but I don't know showing black background part.

thanks.

@update

MainActivity.java (full oncreate)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String nameOfFrontFacingDevice = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();

    if (nameOfFrontFacingDevice != null) {
        VideoCapturerAndroid capturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(nameOfFrontFacingDevice);

        MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        VideoSource videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(capturer, videoConstraints);
        localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, videoSource);

        glview =(GLSurfaceView) findViewById.(R.id.showing);
        VideoRendererGui.setView(glview, null);
        try {
            renderer = VideoRendererGui.createGui(0,0,100,100, VideoRendererGui.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, true);
            localVideoTrack.addRenderer(renderer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream(LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID);
        mediaStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack);
    } else {
        //space
    }
```

I changed my source your advice.
but occur `nullpointerException`

In else part. how can I programmatically?

Comment: thanks @Vinoth Vino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its an app where you are using  camera then, the app should not install in phones that lack this feature. In your manifest put:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    required="true" />
```

**[EDIT]**

According to `VideoCapturerAndroid` source, the following line will return `null` if no camera exist:

```
String nameOfFrontFacingDevice = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();
```

So, in your case this must itself be coming null. However, you are passing the name to `create`. I think this is where NPE is coming from:

```
VideoCapturerAndroid capturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(nameOfFrontFacingDevice); // name might be null
```

So, you should put up a null check here:

```
if (nameOfFrontFacingDevice != null) {
    VideoCapturerAndroid capturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(nameOfFrontFacingDevice);
} else {
    // Other stuff
}
```

**[EDIT 2]**

For devices with no camera, your capturer would still be coming out `null` and that is creating the problem with call to `peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(capturer, videoConstraints)`. Hence, we can make sure we call it only if we have the camera and avoid the NPE. Now, we run into another problem in `glview.onResume()` call in activity `onResume()`. So, we must initialise that before we check for camera. Check the code below for suggested fix:

```
        String nameOfFrontFacingDevice = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();
        String nameOfBackFacingDevice = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfBackFacingDevice();
        Log.i(TAG, "VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice() = " + nameOfFrontFacingDevice);
        Log.i(TAG, "VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfBackFacingDevice() = " + nameOfBackFacingDevice);
        VideoCapturerAndroid capturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(nameOfFrontFacingDevice);

        // Initialising the glview here
        glview = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glview);
        VideoRendererGui.setView(glview, null);

        MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
        if (capturer == null || capturer.equals("")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "not camera");

        }
        // Doing further processing only if capturer is not null
        else {
            VideoSource videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(capturer, videoConstraints);

            localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack(VIDEO_TRACK_ID, videoSource);

            try {
                renderer = VideoRendererGui.createGui(0, 0, 100, 100, VideoRendererGui.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, true);
                renderer_sub = VideoRendererGui.createGui(72, 72, 25, 25, VideoRendererGui.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, true);
                localVideoTrack.addRenderer(renderer_sub);
                localVideoTrack.addRenderer(renderer);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream(LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID);
            mediaStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack);

            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                    finish();
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: No, I'm not acquisition camera permission..  I Intentionally not connect to camera my device..

Comment: @chohyunwook Alright...Check my updated answer above.

Comment: @Shiaishav thanks, but yet occur NullpointerException. please check my update question please!

Comment: @chohyunwook Add `Log.d(''CAM", nameOfFrontFacingCamera);` just to be sure. Also, what line is the NPE pointing to in the logcat?

Comment: `VideoSource videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(capturer, videoConstraints);`   this part. occur NPE

Comment: @chohyunwook Where are you initialising `peerConnectionFactory `?

Comment: ` private PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory;`  is library

Comment: As per the code you need to initialise it: `private PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory;` and then call `peerConnectionFactory = new PeerConnectionFactory();`

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: already I use `peerConnectionFactory = new PeerConnectionFactory();

Comment: @chohyunwook OK ..I can't figure out where the NPE is coming from :( . If you think I can test it on an emulator then you can upload a .zip of the project to DropBox or something and I can try from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120483/discussion-between-chohyunwook-and-shaishav).

Comment: @chohyunwook check my update above. Its no longer crashing for me.

Comment: oh... success this code . :)  why this source work? please reason for me

Comment: @chohyunwook I was basically following the error logs... Since most of them were NPE, I was trying to reason out when they were being initialized :)